# SAS: include values that don't meet a threshold as missing

Tags: sas, proc-sql, proc-report

I am using proc sql and proc report to create a table for my results:

```
proc sql;
create table newtable as
select location, year, month, count(distinct day) as daycount
from have
where threshold>90
group by location, year, month;
quit;

proc report data=newtable;
columns location month year, daycount;
define location/group;
define month/group;
define year/across;
define daycount/analysis sum;
run;
```

The problem I have is that I want all locations, years, and months to appear in the report, even if cells have no values of threshold>90 (and would therefore present as missing). For example, there are 2 locations that have no values of threshold>90 for any month or year, and are excluded entirely from the report. How do I alter my code so that missings are included?

Comment: Your code does exactly what you told it to do: you filter your data by treshold>90. If you want all locations to appear in your report, then delete your where statement. It's not like you have that variable in your report anyway, so removing those locations is the only thing that line does.

Comment: Look at the documentation for PROC REPORT regarding completerows and completecols options

Comment: The where statement is needed so that daycount sums the distinct days with threshold>90. I want those with threshold<=90 to also be included in the report, but to appear as missing or 0. Completerows and completecols is not quite right - it is including all months and years, but 2 locations with no values of threshold>90 are still excluded from the report.

Answer (score 0):

Your where statement filter out data where treshold is lower than 90. If you want to count distinct days only in treshold > 90 but not in the others use case instead:

```
proc sql;
    create table newtable as
        select location, year, month, case 
            when treshold > 90 then count(distinct day) 
            else 0 
        end as daycount
            from have
            group by location, year, month;
quit;
```